# How to define nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to use nested dictionary. I am perl user... So python is much difficult to me. but I start to study python. When I wrote code like below with perl and python. perl is working well but python is not.
Python is good languate to manage many data tree. So can you help me how to control that kinds of data tree..? I have only idea about perl style..

`perl`

```
## working well
$data{apple}{tree}{red}{small}{cheap} = 2;
$data{banana}{tree}{yellow}{big}{cheap} = 3;
$data{grape}{tree}{pupple}{small}{expensive} = 1;
$data{orange}{tree}{orange}{small}{cheap} = 5;

foreach fruite ( sort keys %data) {
  foreach source ( sort keys %{$data{$fruite}}){
    print "$fruite $source\n";
  }
}
```

`python`

```
 data = { }
 data['apple']['tree']['red']['small']['cheap'] = 2
 # not working well..

#ERROR message in python:
#Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "text_parsing.py", line 97, in <module>
# data['apple']['tree']['red']['small']['cheap'] = 2
#KeyError: 'apple'
```

Comment: Do you mean *nested?*

Comment: I've lightly reformatted your Perl code to make it more readable. Please consider doing that yourself in future.

Comment: Thanks to autovivification, `$data{apple}{tree}{red}{small}{cheap}` aka `$data{apple}->{tree}->{red}->{small}->{cheap}` is short for `(((( $data{apple} //= {} )->{tree} //= {} )->{red} //= {} )->{small} //= {} )->{cheap}`

Comment: `s/neshed/nested/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
data = {}
data.setdefault('apple', {}).setdefault('tree', {}).setdefault('red', {}).setdefault('small', {}).setdefault('cheap', 2)
print(data)
# --> {'apple': {'tree': {'red': {'small': {'cheap': 2}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
data = {}
data['apple'] = {'tree':{'red':{'small':{'cheap': 2}}}}
```

After that you can add stuff to the layers like

```
data['apple']['tree']['red']['small']['expensive'] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is a Perl feature called ***autovivification***. If you access a Perl data structure using a key that doesn't already exist, then Perl will create that key for you. This means that you can build up complex data structures very easily using code like yours. Although each of your statements mentions several keys that don't exist, Perl just works out what you mean and creates the structure for you.

Other programming languages don't do that. You can usually only add new keys to a data structure one level at a time.

One way to do it in Python is to create a data structure literal and assign that to your top-level key.

```
data = {}
data['apple']  = {'tree':{'red':{'small':{'cheap': 2}}}}
data['banana'] = {'tree':{'yellow':{'big':}{'cheap: 3}}}}
# etc...
```

The Perl equivalent would be:

```
my %data;
$data{apple}  = {tree => { red => { small => { cheap => 2}}}};
$data{banana} = {tree => { yellow => { big => { cheap => 3}}}};
# etc...
```

This is one of the reasons why I prefer Perl over Python :-)